# An exception in reading data from excel using C# selenium web driver

Tags: c#, excel

I've a problem in reading data from Excel using selenium web driver. I've used "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" and when running my code I found that exception

**System.Runtime.InteropServices.Exception: Excel cannot access 'Downloads'. The document may be read only or encrypted.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgvfw.png)

This is the code I've used
  public void sch_issue_1958M()
        {

```
        Application xlApp = new Application();
        Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\kkhatab\Desktop\3.0.0\Cube.Portal.Regression_for_issuesTests\bin\Downloads");
        Worksheet xlWorkSheet = new Worksheet();
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets[1];
        Range xlRange = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
        int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
        int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;
        for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
            {
                //new line
                if (j == 1)
                    Console.Write("\r\n");

                //write the value to the console
                if (xlRange.Cells[i, j] != null && xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
                    Console.Write(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString() + "\t");


            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Exception on your screenshot says: you are trying to open a **folder** instead of **file**. Look at your 2nd line.

Comment: Shouldn't the file be like (@"C:\Users\kkhatab\Desktop\3.0.0\Cube.Portal.Regression_for_issuesTests\bin\Downloads\myFile.xlsm ?

Comment: and one more thing: your code is using "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel", not "Selenium"

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. It works now

Comment: @vasily.sib, yes the code uses"Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" and it is a part of an issue that uses selenium

Answer (score 0):

**Just for clarity for others:**

Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\kkhatab\Desktop\3.0.0\Cube.Portal.Regression_for_issuesTests\bin\Downloads");

You are trying to open a folder here rather than a document.